# Can LCAs Be Populated/Submitted Through A Third Party Application?

Tags: api, labor

I have a question regarding the Labor Condition Application process that I would really appreciate some insight into.

Specifically, I have been trying to determine whether it is possible to fill out/populate a new ETA Form 9035 outside the iCert web environment, i.e. through a third party web application. On top of that, is it possible to submit a filled out form outside the iCert web environment/through said third party application?

In short, I am looking into the more recent update of 20 CFR 655.734, and am trying to understand what the DOL's limitations are in terms of allowing third party apps to interact with the iCert portal's back end. For example - can an LCA be filled out via a third party interface but still be generated and submitted through iCert (my understanding is that some products provide this already)? Can it go farther?

Thank you!